# Must every Chebyshev subset of a Hilbert space be convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, approximation-theory

Please help me in this question
Its known that every closed convex subset of a Hilbert space is a Chebyshev set.

But is the converse true ? I.e does every Chebyshev subset of a Hilbert space is convex?..Also it is given a fact that If the Hilbert space is finite dimensional, then  the answer is affirmative.

Note that a Chebyshev set is a set having exactly one best approximation.

Thank you in advance

Comment: To answer your follow-up question: yes, [in finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces every Chebyshev set is closed and convex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130393/chebyshev-sets-in-finite-dimension-are-closed-and-convex/1133232#1133232)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is still an open problem.

On the negative side, there is an example of a non-convex Chebyshev set in inner-product spaces, but the one given in a $1987$ paper by G.Johnson, was given in a non-complete inner-product space. On the positive side, it is known that boundedly compact Chebyshev sets in inner-product spaces are convex. (A set $K$ is boundedly compact if each bounded sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence, to some limit in $K$.)