# Must a certain continuous map have 0 in its image, given that its restriction to the unit sphere is homotopic to the identity?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

Suppose $f:\mathbb{B}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous (here $\mathbb{B}^n$ refers to the $n$-dimensional unit ball).  Suppose also that its restriction $g := f|_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$ does not have $0$ in its image, and $g:\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}^n \setminus\{0\}$ is homotopic to the identity map.

Is it necessarily true that $f(x) = 0$ for some $x\in \mathbb{B}^n$?

I have proved it in the affirmative below. I'm hoping there may be a proof that uses only elementary results (i.e. avoids Borsuk-Ulam).  I used this result in the corrected proof of [this question about Chebyshev sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130393/chebyshev-sets-in-finite-dimension-are-closed-and-convex/1133232#1133232).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, by contradiction, $f$ has no zero, then $f|_{\mathbb S^{n-1}}$ is homotopic to a constant in $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ by
$$
H(x,t)=f(tx), \quad x\in S^{n-1}, \ t\in[0,1].
$$
Therefore, by transitivity, the identity map on $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is homotopic to a constant.  However the inclusion of $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ in $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ is easily seen to be a homotopy equivalence so we deduce that $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ is contractible which it obviously isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Write $c\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{B}^n$, with $c \in [0,1]$ and $\mathbf{v}\in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. If $H:\mathbb{S}^{n-1} \times I \to \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ is the assumed homotopy taking $g\to\mathrm{Id}_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}}$, then let $h: \mathbb{B}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by

$$ h(c \mathbf{v}) := \left\{\begin{array}{ll}f(2c\mathbf{v}) &: c\leq 1/2 \\H(\mathbf{v},2c-1) &: c>1/2\end{array}\right.$$

Observe that $h$ restricts to the identity on $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$, which is in particular an odd function, so $h$ has a zero by the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem).  By construction, points in the image of $h$ are either in the image of $f$ or $H$.  And $H$ was presumed to avoid zero, so $f$ must have a zero.