# A question about Introduction online convex optimization Ch2 Ex4

Tags: proof-writing, convex-analysis

The problem: Let $\mathcal{K}\subset R^d$ be a closed and bounded set. $\mathcal{K}$ is a convex set if and only if $\forall x\in R^d, |P_{\mathcal{K}}(x)| =1$ (always exist a unique projection point).

I know how to solve the sufficient condition, that is when $\mathcal{K} $ is a convex set the projection point existing and unique. But I do not know how to prove the necessary condition.

I hope someone kind can help address my concerns

Comment: This is something of a classical problem, first proven in 1934, and has been proven dozens of ways since, none of which are particularly containable in an answer here. If we replace $R^d$ by an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, the question is open, and known as the Chebyshev conjecture. Here's a nice [survey paper](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~moors/chebyshevsurveyJAMS.pdf) on the problem, including some proofs that work in finite dimensions (see section 3). Is this an exercise from a book? If so, then it would help to know what results the chapter covers, to find a suitable proof.

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, this question comes from "Introduction to Online Convex Optimization". Thanks for your comment! I'm really appreciate your help! 
This [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1130393/1295268) show a proof to this problem.