# Behaviour of the nearest point to $x$ on the convex set when $x$ goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact convex set. For $x\in \mathbb R^n$ denote $p(x)$ a unique nearest point to $x$ in $K$, i.e. $|x-p(x)|= \mathrm{dist}(x,K)$. As shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274810/is-a-closed-set-with-the-unique-nearest-point-property-convex) function $p$ is continuous. I'd like to have some properties of this function as $x\to \infty$. Namely, denote $\bar l_x =x/|x|$, so $x=r\bar l_x$, $r>0$.
Is it true that

1. For all $\bar l_x\in S^{n-1}$ there exists a point $p(\infty\bar l_x):=\lim_{r\to+\infty}p(r\bar l_x)$?
2. Does there holds the relation
   $$
   p(x)=p(\infty\bar l_x)+O\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right),\quad x\to \infty? 
   $$
   Meaning, for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $C, R>0$ s.t.
   $
   |p(x)-p(\infty\bar l_x)|\le \frac{C}{|x|}
   $
   if $|x|>R$.

$~$

It seems to be plausible if the boundary $\partial A\in C^1$ and for a ball the asymptotics of $p(x)$ can be written out explicitly: $p(x)=p(\infty\bar l_x)+O\left(\frac{1}{|x|}\right)$. But generally $\partial K$ is just Lipschitz. Secondly, $A$ can have dimention less that $n$, say, to be a segment. The last case can be checked directly though and  I cannot find a counterexample.